# Querying Polymorphic relationship in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, relationship, polymorphism

Does anyone some idea about how to query polymorphics relationships in sqlalchemy?

I have a Persona table with an `id_tipo` field whose values can be `juridica` or `fisica`, and that point to the `PersonaJuridica` table or `PersonanFisica` table repectively.

I am trying to query using a `PersonaJuridica` field this way:

```
session.query(Persona).filter(PersonaJuridica.razon_social == "some value")
```

but it doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
session.query(Persona).join(PersonaJuridica).filter(PersonaJuridica.razon_social == "some value")
```

and I get nothing.

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using the with_polymorphic method of the Query class..
I hadn't seen this!

```
session.query(Persona). with_polymorphic ([PersonaJuridica]).filter(PersonaJuridica.razon_social == "some value")
```

Regards

Comment: could you put the actual answer here?